# Checking to see if an ID is present in another sheet, if not then highlighting cell and creating error message

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet called "1099" which has a list of ID's on (columnB). I want to check whether those ID's are present in my other sheet called "PayerTab"(columnA). If ID is not on PayerTab I want to print an error message "PayorID is missing from list" in column A of "1099"and highlight the cell.

```
Sub Sample()
    Sheets("1099_Recipient_Template").Columns(1).ClearContents
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    Dim rng As Range
    lastRow = Sheets("1099-Misc_Form_Template").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To lastRow
        Set rng = Sheets("1099-Misc_Form_Template").Range("A:A").Find(Sheets("PayorTab").Cells(i, 1))
        If rng Is Nothing Then
            Sheets("1099-Misc_Form_Template").Cells(i, 1).Value = Value & ", Payor ID is not listed"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you using column A for anything other than to just show that line of text? And what further analysis are you planning to do with the lines that get highlighted?

Comment: Column A is being used to list errors throughout my worksheet. Currently not any more analysis, just want the user to know what cells have payerIDs that do not exist in the other tab

Answer (score 0):

In case you plan to just use the highlighted cells as a refence, you could try conditional formatting. Remember values shows, are not actual cell, values.

[image]
Picture 1: PayerTab

[image]
Picture 2: 1099

- Formula in 1099!A:A and drag down.

  ```
  =COUNTIF(PayerTab!A:A,'1099'!B1)
  ```
- Format 1099!A:A text to white color
- Conditional formatting rule on 1099!A:A

  ```
  =$A1=0
  ```
- Conditional format; fill color + text color black + number > custom > "PayerID is missing from list"
- Press ok

Note that because we used a formula in column A, you can still filter on this column to get all cells with "PayorID is missing from list"

Comment: When I put that formula in A:A it starts looking for payerTab in another file, however the Payertab is just another sheet within this file

Comment: @jhill make sure the name is correct and Equal to your sheets name